# Конфликт библиотек jQuery в Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```js
wp_enqueue_script( 'bs', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(popper), '4.5.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js', array(jquery), '1.16.0', true );

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js', false, null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

```html
frontend.min.js?ver=2.9.8:2 Uncaught TypeError: this.elements.$scrollable.animate is not a function
    at child.handleAnchorLinks (frontend.min.js?ver=2.9.8:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.<computed> (frontend-modules.min.js?ver=2.9.8:2)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:formatted:2002)
    at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:formatted:1934)
```

После подключения Bootstrap4 не работают якорные ссылки, гуглил похожие проблемы и насколько я понял, имеется конфликт библиотек jquery или последовательность подключения неправильная. Отключаю библиотеку в ворпресс и включаю другую версию с сайта Bootstrap, плагины которые работали на первой версии не работают, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Нужно использовать нормальную версию jQuery, а не Slim.

Comment: Да, всё оказалось до банальности просто. Убираем вот это ".slim.min." и получаем полную версию jquery. Вот ссылка на версии https://code.jquery.com/, выбираем  uncompressed и копируем ссылку. Это был бы полный ответ.

Comment: Ну и поместите свой комментарий в виде ответа на свой же вопрос, это нормальная практика